# How to train and predict using keras Layers without high-level Model functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In my Tensorflow code, I want to compose my network using Keras Layers like Dense, Dropout and BatchNormalization because I don't want to write the layers myself but I don't want to rely on the sparsely-documented magic of high-level Keras Model functions like Model.fit(). I want to get the loss function, get the train op and apply the back-propagation variable update myself, mostly because I want to understand explicitly what the network is doing and be able to customize the training in ways that Keras does not provide.

If I had only Layers that behave the same during both training and validation/testing/inference, then I could just use Approach 1 [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model) to make a Model, call it with the input tensor to get the prediction tensor and do whatever I need with it for the back-propagation and call it a day.

However, with special layers like Dropout and BatchNormalization, I also need to do these:

- For Dropout, distinguish between training and non-training when getting the prediction, applying dropout only during training.
- For BatchNormalization, before each training step, update the batchnorm statistics.

How can I use Model "the hard way" for training and prediction when Dropout and BatchNormalization are involved? I haven't been able to find any useful examples, and without a high-level explanation the only thing I can do is to dig into the Keras code and trace all manner of overloaded duck-typed functions. More precisely, I don't even need Keras Model per se. I just need a way to compose the Keras Layers for a network with which to do prediction and training.

Comment: What is wrong with approach 1 you mentioned? It can handle for training and inference cases. Just set `training = False`, when using call method for inference.

Comment: @Mitiku I see no 'call' function in the documentation at tensorflow.org. Do you mean `__call__()`? Assuming that `__call__()` with `training` does the right thing for Dropout, I still need to update the batchnorm stats during training and I don't see how the use of `__call__()` you described addresses that.